# Google Slides API reports Invalid requests[0].updateTableCellProperties: Invalid field: table_cell_properties

Tags: google-slides-api

Trying to troubleshoot an error message my app gets after sending a `batchUpdate` request to Google Slides API

```
Invalid requests[19].updateTableCellProperties: Invalid field: table_cell_properties
```

The 19th request in the batch is the only `updateTableCellProperties` request I have. If I removing the 19th request from the batch, everything works fine.

Other requests which I run in this `batchUpdate` with no issues are are `insertTableRows`, `deleteTableRow`, `insertText`, `updateParagraphStyle`, `updateTextStyle`, `updateTableColumnProperties`. They all work on the same table, so I use the same `objectId`, but depending on the request I have to specify it as `tableObjectId` instead of `objectId`.

Unsure if I am generating a wrong request for the only `updateTableCellProperties` request I have, or if there is a problem in the Google Slides ruby gem itself, I tried sending just this `updateTableCellProperties` request from the Google Slides API explorer which has some validation on the request structure. So I sent [this `updateTableCellProperties` `batchUpdate` request](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22presentationId%22%3A%221dScb934481aHzk3489x9348567no9FFmtpx-0cwoumY%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22updateTableCellProperties%22%3A%7B%22objectId%22%3A%22gf9d8fea71f_22_1%22%2C%22tableRange%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22columnIndex%22%3A0%2C%22rowIndex%22%3A1%7D%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22tableCellProperties%22%2C%22tableCellProperties%22%3A%7B%22tableCellBackgroundFill%22%3A%7B%22solidFill%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%7B%22themeColor%22%3A%22LIGHT1%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D)

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateTableCellProperties": {
        "objectId": "gf9d8fea71f_22_1",
        "tableRange": {
          "location": {
            "columnIndex": 0,
            "rowIndex": 1
          }
        },
        "fields": "tableCellProperties",
        "tableCellProperties": {
          "tableCellBackgroundFill": {
            "solidFill": {
              "color": {
                "themeColor": "LIGHT1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I got this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[0].updateTableCellProperties: Invalid field: table_cell_properties",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Why is this `updateTableCellProperties` request reported as invalid? I am also confused by the output of the error message as it mentions `table_cell_properties` in snake case, while the documentation only mentions `tableCellProperties` in camel case, and my request also only mentions `tableCellProperties` in camel case. I am only aware of the ruby gems translating between snake case and camel case, but this is not relevant to the API Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The error `Invalid field: table_cell_properties` originates from the erroneously specified `fields` property

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetablecellpropertiesrequest):

> fields

> At least one field must be specified. The root tableCellProperties is implied and should not be specified. A single "*" can be used as short-hand for listing every field.

So you need to modify `fields`

from

`"fields": "tableCellProperties"`

to

`"fields": "tableCellBackgroundFill.solidFill.color"`

or to

`"fields": "*"`

**There is a second problem with your request:**

When specifying the [table range](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#tablerange), it is required to set the properties `rowSpan` and `columnSpan`.

A complete, correct request would be:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateTableCellProperties": {
        "objectId": "gf9d8fea71f_22_1",
        "tableRange": {
          "location": {
            "columnIndex": 0,
            "rowIndex": 1
          },
          "rowSpan": 1,
          "columnSpan": 1
        },
        "fields": "tableCellBackgroundFill.solidFill.color",
        "tableCellProperties": {
          "tableCellBackgroundFill": {
            "solidFill": {
              "color": {
                "themeColor": "LIGHT1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Spot on! After fixing the original `fields` issue, I did get errors about the rowSpan and columnSpan which was a clear enough message that is easy to correct.